# What is causing this strange shading on my mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

Theres this weird thing happening here.  Ive tried to merge all vertices, I can't see any mesh under it,  Ive tried to grab and pull it around but I always have this weird highlighted line here.

Comment: seems like a pinch where a vertex or an edge was extruded inside the mesh?

Comment: How would I be able to figure that out?

Comment: Look at the object in Xray view, and then Select -> Select all by trait -> Non-manifold should give some hint

Comment: A few diagnostic routines.. H hide a few faces and look inside... jiggle some vertices to check for doubles, in 'Overlays', switch on 'Face Orientation' to check for inverted normals..

Comment: If it helps I extruded new vertacies to make some quads and it looks like there's an edge but without a selectable edge. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  One of the edges wasnt connected to the face.  I deleted the face underneath and created new faces

Comment: The 3D Print add-on is a helpful tool for these sorts of problems. It can show you intersecting faces and non-manifold edges (open edges that would make a hole where “water” would spill out of making the object not “water-tight”).